# Responsive Design: switching order of Div's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple page.  What I want to do is when I make the width smaller, I would like the "middle" div to be on top of the "left" div.  Right now, the middle div is second as it should be, but I'm wondering how I would make it so that the middle div goes on top of the left div.

http://jsfiddle.net/nynou9mr/

```css
div{
 font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 font-size:60px;
}

body{
 margin:0;padding:0;
}

#header{
 height:100px;
 width:100%;
 background:purple;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
}

.wrap{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:blue;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}


#left{
 display: inline-block;
    margin-top:10px;  
 height:500px;
 width:300px;
 background:red;
}

#middle{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top:10px;   
 margin-left:10px;
 height:500px;
 width:1570px;
 background:gray;
}


@media (max-width:1320px){
 #left{
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px auto;display:block;
 }
 #middle{
  width:800px;
 }
 #bottom{
  margin-top:100px;
 }
}

@media (max-width:1625px){
    #right{
   width:100%;
   height:300px;
    }

}


/* -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=For Footer */
* {
 padding: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding:0;
}

.forfooter{
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#bottom{
 /*position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;*/
 height:100px;
 background:orange;
}

.push{
 height:0px;
 margin-top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<title>First Responsiveness</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="forfooter">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  
        <div class="wrap">
   <div id="left">left</div>
   <div id="middle">Middle</div>
        </div>
        
  <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

  <div class="push"></div>
  <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: take a look at css media queries (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Do it the other way around. Put the middle element above the left element so that they are in the right place in the narrow mode, then fix the positions in the wide mode.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what browser support you need.

`flexbox` makes this easy.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 25px;
}
#left,
#middle {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  order: 1;
}
#left {
  background: #bada55;
}
#middle {
  background: #663399;
  color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #middle {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div id="left">left</div>

  <div id="middle">Middle</div>
  
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qOEvjz)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/e42q63w5/1/
The trick is to have `div#middle` before `div#left` in your html and control the position with `float: left | right`

```css
div{
 font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 font-size:60px;
}

body{
 margin:0;padding:0;
}
#header{
 height:100px;
 width:100%;
 background:purple;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
}

.wrap{
 
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 background:blue;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;

}


#left{
 float: left
 display: inline-block;
    margin-top:10px;  
 height:500px;
 width:20%;
 background:red;
}

#middle{
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top:10px;   
 margin-left:10px;

 height:500px;
 width:75%;
 background:gray;
}

@media (max-width:1320px){
 #left{
     float: none;
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  margin:20px auto;
        display:block;
 }
  #middle{
     float: none;      
  width:800px;
 }
 #bottom{
  margin-top:100px;
 }
}
@media (max-width:1625px){
#right{
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
}

}


/* -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=For Footer */
* {
 padding: 0;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 padding:0;
}

.forfooter{
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

#bottom{
 /*position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;*/
 height:100px;
 background:orange;
}


.push{
 height:0px;
 margin-top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="forfooter">
        <div id="header">Header</div>

        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="middle">Middle</div>
            
            <div id="left">left</div>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>

    </div>
 <div class="push"></div>
        <div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </div>
```